# success message not displying in phtml template

Tags: magento2.3.3

**Success Message Not Display**

> In Controller :-

```
public function execute()
{

      $delid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

      try{
         $user = $this->_userFactory->create();
         $user->load($delid);
         $user->delete();
         }catch (\Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
         }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Record Deleted   
        Successfully.!'));
        $this->_redirect('magecompcrud/user/user')
}
```

[image]

**Thanks in advance:)**

Comment: check   class="page messages" exist in page or not.

Answer (score 0):

Working with message manager

Messaging in Magento 2 is handled by a message manager object. So if you want to write messages, you need to get an instance of it. The prefered method is to inject this class into your class by adding this to your __construct method:

```
protected messageManager;

public function __construct(
    ... 
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    ...
){
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    ...
}
```

With this, you can call one of the following messages:
PHP

```
$this->messageManager->addError(__("Error"));
$this->messageManager->addWarning(__("Warning"));
$this->messageManager->addNotice(__("Notice"));
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("Success"));
```